# Changing DAG network

Tags: exchange-2016, dag

We have a separate DAG replication network than the MAPI network for our exchange 2016 pair. We want to get rid of the separate DAG network and use the same MAPI network for replication.

How do we accomplish this? Do we just simply delete current DAG configuration and re-create a new one?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also see here, please read it has some caveats
https://www.exchangeitup.net/2016/09/exchange-2016-removing-dag-network.html

Answer (score 1):

A [DAG network](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/managing-database-availability-groups-exchange-2013-help#dag-networks) is a collection of one or more subnets used for either replication traffic or MAPI traffic. Each DAG contains a maximum of one MAPI network and zero or more replication networks.

We could use the Set-DatabaseAvailabilityGroupNetwork cmdlet to configure DAG network properties.
[image]

And some related links:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ed1c6a6f-5706-4cee-928d-f68d34e52e0e/configure-dag-replication-network?forum=exchangesvravailabilityandisasterrecovery

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e3008a3-a243-47b9-aa8c-0fb3e8a14558/seed-mailbox-database-copy-through-replication-network-dag-members-on-different-subnets-in?forum=exchangesvrdeploy